# Change AR session config after fragment created

Tags: kotlin, arcore, sceneform

I want to re-configure AR session after session has been running. I want to change Augmented Images database.

I don't seem to find a way to set the reset the session configuration.

```
getSessionConfiguration(Session session)
```

This function only seems to be called once at the beginning.

Is there a way to re-configure? Should I not be using the fragment?

Answer (score 1):

I make changes to my config on the fly. You can accomplish this by extending ARFragment and having access to the config or simply be accessing the ARFragment from your xml within your activity. Here is an example.

```
arSceneView.session?.apply {
     val changedConfig = config
     changedConfig.planeFindingMode = Config.PlaneFindingMode.HORIZONTAL_AND_VERTICAL
     configure(changedConfig)
}
```

That's it, just call configure(myNewConfig) and it will update it for you.
Of course in this example, I get the current config, modify it and put it back, but you could replace it if preferred.